# Does GWT linkers supports parameters?

Tags: gwt

I would like to reuse my GWT linker in several projects, with different configurations. Is it possible to define properties or parameters to the linker in my module configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [LinkerContext](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/ext/LinkerContext.html#getConfigurationProperties()) to get ConfigurationProperty, it contains all configurationproperty-values in your module.

To set a configuration property value:

```
<set-configuration-property name="Patrik" value="wasHere" />
```